# Debugging information for 'mpiexec' cannot be found or doesn't match.Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing, mpi

I am going to start parallel programming using MPI on visual studio c++ 2010. I made all configurations for MPI. Now i can run any MPI program from command prompt, but I want to make the call from visual studio. So I followed the steps in this [screen shot](http://supercomputingblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/configure_command_line.JPG)

and I got this error :

```
Debugging information for 'mpiexec' cannot be found or doesn't match.Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

So what should i do ?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 SDK adds an additional debugger type to Visual Studio 2010 - *MPI Cluster Debugger*. It could be selected in the *Debugger to launch* drop down control on the same configuration page that is shown on the screenshot in your question.

[Here](https://sharepoint.campus.rwth-aachen.de/units/rz/HPC/public/Shared%20Documents/03_MSMPI_and_C_CPP_in_VS2010.pdf) is a terse one-page how-to on building and debugging MPI projects with VS 2010 and MS HPC Pack SDK that I have created for one of our parallel programming workshops.